# Short story about an island nation blockaded because of hijacking

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

An island nation, presumably on Earth not very far in our future, has been blockaded for decades from the rest of the world because its leaders backed a series of hijackings. No one has crossed its shores for years. Now the island is poor and the harbor cranes are rusting, and, if memory serves, its aged leader is passing control to a new leader. He is shocked to learn that the new man not only favors a return to hijacking, but has already hijacked a cargo ship. "But you know what they said they'd do the next time," he says, or words to that effect. The new man just sneers at the old man's weakness. And then the nuclear bombs start to fall on the island.

I don't know the date of this work of alternate history, but I thought at the time that the author could be inspired by the [airplane hijackings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_hijacking) that were common in the 1960s. Many of these planes ended up in the island nation of Cuba, and the story seems to suggest a way to treat nations that act as havens for hijackers. Accordingly, a date in the 1960s or 70s seems likely. The story was in English and I very likely read it in a science fiction anthology.

Comment: Can you clarify the science fiction and/or fantasy aspects, other than there not having been such a foreign island blockaded in our history?

Comment: I believe that I read it in a science fiction anthology. Presumably the story falls under the category of alternate history as it has not happened and was not intended as historical fiction. But there were no aspects that could not happen in a slightly modified version of our own Earth. I'll edit the question to make that clear.